# How do I restore state if a view controller gets unloaded due to a memory warning?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a view controller that gets a property set by the view controller it gets pushed from.

Basically, I have something like

```
- (void)doStuff {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToThing" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueToThing"])
        [(ThingViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setImportantData:[self importantData]];
}
```

The problem is, if I push `ThingViewController` and then push another view controller on top of it, then issue a memory warning, my `ThingViewController` gets unloaded to release memory. Then I pop the third view controller and my `ThingViewController` gets loaded again, but the `importantData` property I set in the segue is `nil` now because the segue didn't get fired again.

What do I do about this? Am I supposed to store all my state somewhere...?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to release that memory, then don't release it in the memory warning or viewDidUnload.

If you need to release the memory, persist the data and then reload it when the VC comes back.

Comment: I tried not releasing it in my viewDidUnload, but the VC seems to get completely torn down and rebuilt and loses all its properties when the memory warning occurs. Could you elaborate a bit on how I would persist this data? Do I have to do something stupid like stuff it in a static variable or something?

Comment: You should post a bit of code, namely anything related the the view controller lifecycle (viewDidLoad/Unload initializers, didReceiveMemoryWarning, etc) and your management of that important thing that is disappearing.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps store the important data in the `AppDelegate`? In your AppDelegate.h file declare an `NSData` object or whatever object that needs to be saved. Then during `prepareForSegue` you get a reference to the `AppDelegate` like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And then save your object with the variable that you saved in the AppDelegate. Then when the second view gets loaded again just call the AppDelegate again and use the data from the App Delegate. Hopefully that can help. Let me know if you need more help or if I was unclear.

Comment: I considered that, but I was hoping there would be a better way. I mean, if `prepareForSegue:` is provided for the whole purpose of doing what I'm doing, I don't see why the default `UIViewController` memory warning behavior is to throw out that data.

Comment: I see. Why are you issuing a low memory warning? Maybe you can do without that.

Comment: I'm just simulating the memory warning to test. I've noticed when the app is running it gets memory warnings a lot when using a `UIWebView`.

Comment: No, do not do that.  Look at the name of that class... AppDelegate.  It's for handling delegated methods from UIApplication.  It's not a dumping ground for design refuse.